# Simple (?) redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

this is probably simple but i don't know how to do it.

I want all links of this form: http://www.fractalbit.gr/archives/xxx
to redirect to this: http://www.fractalbit.gr/?p=xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch .*\/archives\/(.+) http://www.fractalbit.gr/?p=$1
```

[RedirectMatch in Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^archives/(.+)$ ?p=$1
```

All depends however, a lot on whether you are allowed to use .htaccess in such a way. Stuff like this is not always permitted by webhosts.

PS: this is called rewriting as opposed to redirecting, but I think this is what you mean.

Comment: This is probably correct but it does not work as intended and it is my fault, i should have said that i am using wordpress and i already have an .htaccess file with the followin contents# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php  
</IfModule>

Comment: Well that explains. Good to see that another answer did help you out!